# If $\forall x \in (0,1] \ \ f_n(x) \to 0, n \to \infty$ then $\exists x_n \downarrow 0$ such that $f_n(x_n) \to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, sequence-of-function

In the second edition of the book "Probability" (A. N. Shiryaev, R.P. Boas, 1996) there is a problem 2, p. 553 ($\S$ 8, chapter VII) which is equivalent to the next one. Suppose that for every $n \ge 1$  $f_n(x): (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.

If $\forall x \in (0,1] \ \  f_n(x) \to 0, n \to \infty$ then $\exists x_n \downarrow 0$ (strictly monotone) such that $f_n(x_n) \to 0$.

This problem is an important part of the proof of CLT for martingales.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $f_n(x) \ge 0$ (because we may consider $\tilde{f}_n(x) = |f_n(x)|$). Let's consider this case.

It is easy to prove that if conditions of the problem hold true then $\exists x_n \to 0$ such that $f_n(x_n) \to 0$. Sketch of this proof: we show that $\inf_{x \in (0,1]} (x + f_n(x)) \to 0$ (by contradiction) and find $x_n$ such that $x_n \le \inf_{x \in (0,1]} (x + f_n(x)) + \frac1{n}$. Unfortunately, $x_n$ from this proof may be not strictly monotone.

I also can solve the problem in case when there is the next additional condition: $\forall x \in (0,1]$  $f_n(x)$ has the set $E_n$ of discontinuities with Lebesgue measure $\mu(E_n) = 0$ [e.g. $f_n(x)$ is monotone function of $x$].
Idea of the proof: $E = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$. We will work with $(0,1] \backslash E \ $ $ \ $ instead of $(0,1]$. Denote by $\tilde{x}_n \to 0$ the sequence from the previous proof, which is identical if we have $(0,1] \backslash E$ instead of $(0,1]$. It's easy to find $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$ such that $\tilde{x}_{n_k} \downarrow 0$. Put $x_{n_k} =\tilde{x}_{n_k}$. We can find $x_{n_1 + 1} > x_{n_1 + 2} >  \ldots > x_{n_2-1}$ in a little left neighborhood of $x_{n_1}$, then we can find $x_{n_2 + 1} > x_{n_2 + 2} >  \ldots > x_{n_3-1}$ in a little left neighborhood of $x_{n_2}$ and so on and make a sequence $x_{n}$ such that $f_n(x_n) \to 0$.

My question: how to solve the problem without any additional assumptions?

Comment: What are the assumptions? Is $f$ continuous on $(0,1]$?

Comment: The onliest assumption is the next one: $\forall x \in (0,1] \ \  f_n(x) \to 0, n \to \infty$. In case when all $f_n(x)$ are continious I know how to solve the problem (and in more general case, when $\mu(E_n) = 0$).

Comment: Do you interpret $x_n\downarrow 0$ as strictly or weakly monotone?

Comment: It's strictly monotone sequence

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy  That approach still has a gap: Let $b_{n}=\liminf_{x\rightarrow0+}[x+f_{n}(x)]$.
We have difficulty in proving that $b_{n}\rightarrow0$. For example,
suppose the contrary that $b_{n}\not\rightarrow0$. By passing to
a subsequence, without loss of generality, we may assume that there
exists $c>0$ such that $b_{n}>c$ for all $n$. For each $n$, there
exists $\delta_{n}>0$ such that $\inf_{x\in(0,\delta_{n})}[x+f_{n}(x)]>c$.
It may happen that $\delta_{n}\rightarrow0$, so we may be
unable to choose an $x_{0}$, sufficiently close to $0$, such that
$x_{0}+f_{n}(x_{0})>c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $g(1) = 1$ and for $n\geq 2$ let $g(n)$ denote the minimal $n$ strictly greater than $g(n-1)$ for which there exists an infinite subset $A_n
\subset (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ such that for $m \geq g(n)$, for every $x \in A_n$ $$f_m(x) \leq \frac{1}{n}$$ Then for all $n > 1$ and $g(n) \leq k < g(n+1)$, Let $x_k$ be a strictly decreasing sequence in $A_n$.

Comment: Where letter m is used? Did you mean $f_m(x) \le \frac1{n}$ or $f_n(x) \le \frac{1}m$? Could you please explain why $g(n)$ exists?

Comment: Yes, I meant $f_m$.    $g(n)$ exists because suppose $B_N$ is the set of all $x \in (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1})$ such that for $m \geq N$, $f_m(x) \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Then every $x$ is in some $B_N$ so the union of all $B_N$ in uncountable, so at least one $B_N$ must be uncountable because the countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: There is a little misprint: you define $ g(n)$ recursively as minimal $n > g(n)$ with some property (but if we know $n-1$ then $n$ is fixed ), so we may define $g(n)$ as the minimal natural number strictly greater than $g(n-1)$ with properties that you wrote. If I'm right, you meant it. There is another interpretation of your proof in answers above. All the same everything is clear and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n_m$ be indices such that
$$
f_n(1/m) < 1/m \qquad \forall n\ge n_m
$$
and notice that you can take $n_m$ strictly crescent in $m$. Now take
$$
x_n = 1/m \qquad n_{m+1}>n\ge n_m 
$$
and notice that
$$
f_n(x_n) < 1/m \to 0
$$

Comment: But in this case $x_n$ are not strictly monotone. I reformulated my question in order to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

I elaborate and clarify cha21's solution. Let $f_n:(0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a function such that for each $x\in(0,1], f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$.

We define a sequence of positive integers $(n_{k})$ such that $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$
by recursion: Define $n_{1}=1$. Suppose that $n_{1},n_{2},\ldots,n_{k}$
have been specified. Note that 
$$
(\frac{1}{n_{k}+1},\frac{1}{n_{k}})=\bigcup_{L=1}^{\infty}A_{L}^{(k)},
$$
where $A_{L}^{(k)}=\left\{ x\in(\frac{1}{n_{k}+1},\frac{1}{n_{k}})\mid\forall l\geq L\,\,\,f_{l}(x)\leq\frac{1}{n_{k}}\right\} $.
Since $(\frac{1}{n_{k}+1},\frac{1}{n_{k}})$ is uncountable, there
exists $L$ such that $A_{L}^{(k)}$ is uncountable. Clearly, $A_{1}^{(k)}\subseteq A_{2}^{(k)}\subseteq\ldots$,
so we may choose $L$ such that $L>n_{k}$ and $A_{L}^{(k)}$ is uncountable.
Let $n_{k+1}$ be any such $L$. Also observe that $A_{n_{k+1}}^{(k)}\subseteq(\frac{1}{n_{k}+1},\frac{1}{n_{k}})$,
so $A_{n_{2}}^{(1)},A_{n_{3}}^{(2)},\ldots$ are pairwisely disjoint.
Moreover, for any $x\in A_{n_{i+1}}^{(i)}$, $y\in A_{n_{j+1}}^{(j)}$,
we have $x>y$ if $i<j$.

Partition the set 
$$
\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\{m\mid n_{k}\leq m<n_{k+1}\}.
$$
For $m\in\{m\mid n_{k+1}\leq m<n_{k+2}\}$, we choose $x_{m}\in A_{n_{k+1}}^{(k)}$
such that $x_{n_{k+1}}>x_{n_{k+1}+1}>\dots$. For $m\in\{m\mid1\leq m<n_{2}\}$,
Choose $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n_{2}-1}$ in an arbitrary way such
that $x_{1}>x_{2}>\ldots>x_{n_{2}-1}>x_{n_{2}}$. This is possible
because $x_{n_{2}}<1$. Clearly $(x_{m})$ is a strictly decreasing
sequence in $(0,1)$, $x_{m}\rightarrow0$. Moreover, if $n_{k+1}\leq m<n_{k+2}$,
then $x_{m}\in A_{n_{k+1}}^{(k)}$ and hence $f_{m}(x_{m})\leq\frac{1}{n_{k}}$
because the condition $m\geq n_{k+1}$ is satisfied. It follows that
$f_{m}(x_{m})\rightarrow0$.

Comment: I understood cha21's definition of $g(n)$ differently: $g(n)$ is the minimal natural number strictly greater than $g(n-1)$ for which there exists an infinite subset $A_n \subset (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ such that for $m \ge g(n)$ for every $x \in A_n$ we have $f_m(x) \le \frac{1}{n}$. If we use this definition, cha21's solution works. In your notation it means that we may consider $(\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{1}{k})$ instead of $(\frac{1}{n_k+1}, \frac{1}{n_k})$: it is a little more natural. All the same both clarifications of cha21's solution work.